# Better way to count multiple elements in a string

Tags: python, count

```
def get_count(input_str):
    
    return input_str.count("a") + input_str.count("e") + input_str.count("i") + input_str.count("o") + input_str.count("u")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "hi what's up by there?"

lookup = ["e", "i", "u"]

print([s.count(x) for x in lookup])
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 1]
```

In a function:

```
def lookup_count(s, lookup):
    return [s.count(x) for x in lookup]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this in two ways:

First:

```
def get_count(input_str, target_str='aeiou'):
    return sum(map(input_str.count,target_str))
```

You can also use collections.Counter

```
from collections import Counter
def get_count(input_str, target_str='aeiou'):
    cnt = Counter(input_str)
    return sum([cnt[chr] for chr in target_str])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two strings: one that is your target, and one that is your search set.  You have to loop through one of them and search the other.  Which way is better depends on the length of the strings.